# EMR Spark Fails to Save Dataframe to S3

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am using the `RunJobFlow` command to spin up a Spark EMR cluster. This command sets the `JobFlowRole` to an IAM Role which has the policies `AmazonElasticMapReduceforEC2Role` and `AmazonRedshiftReadOnlyAccess`. The first policy contains an action to allow all s3 permissions.

When the EC2 instances spin up, they assume this IAM role, and generate temporary credentials via STS.

The first thing which I do is read a table from my Redshift cluster into a Spark Dataframe using the `com.databricks.spark.redshift` format and using the same IAM Role to unload the data from redshift as I did for the EMR `JobFlowRole`.

So far as I understand, this runs an `UNLOAD` command on Redshift to dump into the S3 bucket I specify. Spark then loads the newly unloaded data into a Dataframe. I use the recommended `s3n://` protocol for the `tempdir` option.

This command works great, and it always successfully loads the data into the Dataframe.

I then run some transformations and attempt to save the dataframe in the `csv` format to the same S3 bucket Redshift `Unloaded` into.

However, when I try to do this, it throws the following error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key must be specified as the username or password (respectively) of a s3n URL, or by setting the fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId or fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey properties (respectively)`

Okay. So I don't know why this happens, but I tried to hack around it by setting the recommended hadoop configuration parameters. I then used `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` to load the `AWSAccessKeyID` and `AWSSecretKey` and set via

`spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", <CREDENTIALS_ACCESS_KEY>)
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", <CREDENTIALS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>)`

When I run it again it throws the following error:

`java.io.IOException: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidAccessKeyId;`

Okay. So that didn't work. I then removed setting the hadoop configurations and hardcoded an IAM user's credentials in the s3 url via `s3n://ACCESS_KEY:SECRET_KEY@BUCKET/KEY`

When I ran this it spit out the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bucket name should be between 3 and 63 characters long`

So it tried to create a bucket.. which is definitely not what we want it to do.

I am really stuck on this one and would really appreciate any help here! It works fine when I run it locally, but completely fails on EMR.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the following:

- EC2 Instance Generated Temporary Credentials on EMR Bootstrap Phase
- When I queried Redshift, I passed the `aws_iam_role` to theDatabricks driver. The driver then re-generated temporary credentials for that same IAM role. This invalidated the credentials the EC2 instance generated.
- I then tried to upload to S3 using the old credentials (and the credentials which were stored in the instance's metadata)

It failed because it was trying to use out-of-date credentials.

The solution was to remove redshift authorization via `aws_iam_role` and replace it with the following:

`val credentials = EC2MetadataUtils.getIAMSecurityCredentials
...
.option("temporary_aws_access_key_id", credentials.get(IAM_ROLE).accessKeyId)
.option("temporary_aws_secret_access_key", credentials.get(IAM_ROLE).secretAccessKey)
.option("temporary_aws_session_token", credentials.get(IAM_ROLE).token)`

Answer (score 0):

On amazon EMR, try usong the prefix s3:// to refer to an object in S3.

It's [a long story](http://hortonworks.com/blog/history-apache-hadoops-support-amazon-s3/).